# How to get the EC2 instance IP created by an AutoScaling Group?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I created an ECS cluster with an AutoScaling Group like so:

```
const cluster = new ecs.Cluster (
    this,
    "ECSCluster",
    {
        clusterName: "myCluster",
        vpc: my-vpc
    }
);

const autoScalingGroup = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup (
    this,
    "autoScalingGroup",
    {
        autoScalingGroupName: "myAutoScalingGroup",
        vpc: my-vpc,
        instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType("t3.2xlarge"),
        ... 
    }
);

const capacityProvider = new ecs.AsgCapacityProvider (
    this,
    "capacityProvider",
    { autoScalingGroup }
);

cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(capacityProvider);
```

So this code creates an EC2 instance as well and now I would like to get the private IP of this instance to add it as a record in Route53.

Following the code above, I tried something like this with SDK:

```
const EC2Client = new sdk.EC2();
const params = {
    Filters: [
        {
            Name: "instance-state-name",
            Values: ["running"]
        },
        {
            Name: "tag:Name",
            Values: ["my-ecs-name"]
        }
    ]
}

const response = await EC2Client.describeInstances(params).promsie();
const privateIP = response.Reservations?.[0].Instances?.[0].PrivateIpAddress ?? "";
```

But I've got this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Instances')". I think the issue here is I cannot fetch this instance because it's not created yet. How can I wait for the creation or what can I do to get this IP and add it in my HostedZone records?

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: How are you running the SDK code?

Comment: Directly inside the SDK but I think I will have to do it after

Comment: inside the CDK, you mean? Yeah, that will not work. The CDK code is not deploying anything, it's simply generating a cloudformation template that can be deployed afterwards. 
And in any case - you are deploying an ASG, not an instance, so you cannot simply set up a single instance and forget about the rest that may be launched.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to updated the record within the EC2 instance during load with an InitConfig instead.

https://subaud.io/blog/building-an-ec2-instance-with-cdkv2-and-cloud-init